# Why is PowerShell job not starting?

Tags: powershell, jobs

This code is not working:

```
$scriptBlock = {
  Param($i)
  $i
}

for ($i=1; $i -le 2; $i++) {
  Start-Job -ArgumentList $i -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock | Out-Null
}
sleep 5
Get-Job
Write-Host "end"
```

Output:

```
Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------
2      Job2            BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            ...
4      Job4            BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            ...
end
```

As you can see, the jobs are still running when they should finish very quickly. In fact, this

```
(Get-Job -Id 2).ChildJobs
```

would give me

```
Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------
3      Job3                            NotStarted    True            localhost            ...
```

Notice **NotStarted**. Any idea why it is never started?

Note: this also hangs PowershellISE.

However, if I put in a break point in the beginning and step through the script, everything works fine.

Comment: Could you please post the script. and also post what you are doing inside the script block . What command you are running inside the job

Comment: Can't reproduce. The code you posted starts and terminates jobs as it should for me. Did you try starting PowerShell without profile settings (`powershell.exe -NoProfile`) to make sure that no settings in your profile cause this behavior?

Comment: Ansgar Wiechers, oh, good call! It looks like it fails if my profile loads when running from Powershell ISE and succeeds if it does not. I also tried with regular Powershell and it succeeds either way. I do have Powershell Community Extensions and some other stuff loading. It must be that!